# Android ScrollView only scroll to bottom if you're already there

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I have a basic android app set up with a scroll view and text added to it dynamically.
I want it to scroll to the bottom when text is added (which already happens) but I only want it to scroll to the bottom if you are already at the bottom, so if you're reading something it doesn't just scroll.
Here's what I have so far.

```
private void AddText(final String msg){
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextView log = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatlog);
            if(log.getText().equals("Loading...")){
                log.setText(msg);
            }else{
                ScrollView scroller = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_container);
                //set current scroll position
                int scroll_pos = scroller.getScrollY();
                //scroll to bottom
                scroller.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                //set bottom position
                int scroll_bot = scroller.getScrollY();
                //add the text
                log.append("\r\n" + msg);
                //if you weren't at the bottom
                //scroll back to where you were.
                //This isn't working, scroll bot is the same
                //as scroll pos.
                if(scroll_pos != scroll_bot){
                    scroller.scrollTo(0, scroll_pos);
                }
                //System.out.println("Pos: " + scroll_pos);
                //System.out.println("Bot: " + scroll_bot);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I found so far is to use scrollView.post() method with a runnable that will be invoked after text change:

```
final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.consoleTab);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.consoleView);
boolean autoScroll = (textView.getBottom() - (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY())) <= 0;
textView.setText(state.getConsole().getText());

if (autoScroll) {
   scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example I got running in the emulator and on my galaxy s.
Basically there are two buttons to add text to the bottom text view, depending on your devices size only the second of these should be usable to see the autoscrolling.  The textview being edited uses the ontextchangedlistener to check the scroll position before its text is changed and then to call a delayed (so the screen can update with the additional text) autoscroll where appropriate, after the text has changed.

The layout xml is as follows:

```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/scrollmain">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainRelative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >  
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to the scrolling test application!" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/firstTextAddButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleText"
        android:text="Click me to add text to the textview below without scrolling"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/secondTextAddButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstTextAddButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
        android:text="Click me to add text to the textview below and scroll (if you are currently scrolled all the way to the bottom)"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textToEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secondTextAddButton"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Some text to get us started."/>
        />
</RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

And the code for the activity is as follows:

```
  package code.example.scrollingontextchange;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.Handler;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.text.Editable;
  import android.text.TextWatcher;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
  import android.widget.ScrollView;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private int scroll_pos;
private int maxScrollPosition;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textToEdit);
    tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {              
            if(scroll_pos == maxScrollPosition)
            {
                Handler h = new android.os.Handler()
                {
                    @Override             
                    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) 
                    {                 
                        switch(msg.what)
                        {
                            case 0 :
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                                ScrollView scrll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollmain);
                                scrll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                                break;                              
                            default :
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                };
                h.sendEmptyMessage(0);                  
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            ScrollView scrll = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollmain);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainRelative);

            scroll_pos = scrll.getScrollY();

            maxScrollPosition = rl.getHeight() - scrll.getHeight();             
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }           
    });

    OnClickListener addTextOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textToEdit);
            tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\nA long time ago, in a galaxy s far far away............");
        }           
    };

    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.firstTextAddButton);
    b.setOnClickListener(addTextOnClick);
    Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.secondTextAddButton);
    b2.setOnClickListener(addTextOnClick);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you will need to do the comparison at the time but change the scroll position in a seperate thread with a delay in order to allow your text to render onscreen before you scroll, otherwise when you call 'scroller.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);' it scrolls to the current bottom of the screen which hasn't yet been updated with your text.  Will try and post some example code in the next couple of days if you haven't managed it by then.

Comment: But what I want it to do is, if your scroll position is at the bottom, it scrolls to the bottom when new text is added, if you are up a bit reading smoething it just appends it and lets you keep reading what you were. But it doesn't seem possible from what iv'e seen.

Comment: I have changed my answer above to be a fully implemented solution instead of the code snippet I gave before.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me why, but setting your `TextView`'s gravity to `bottom` it does exactly what you want.